# Adding Crashlytics SDK causes crash on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, google-analytics, testflight, crashlytics

Having successfully integrated the Crashlytics SDK into my existing iOS (iPad) app, everything runs fine on the simulator.

When trying to run the app on a device it falls over at this point in my app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
    return YES
}
```

The app codebase has a legacy integration of both Testflight and Google Analytics.

This occurs when building straight from xCode and when deploying using the Fabric platform

Using a duplicated Scheme with slightly different bundle ID enables the app to run fine.

Comment: Could you solve this problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: I have solved it but I honestly can't remember what the problem was. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue with the provisioning profile while trying to install the app on device for testing.